# How to compare 2 values in the same column based on values from a different column with SQL, then store the result in a new column?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I have the following table:

| Time | Stage | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 09:00 | 1 | Ben |
| 09:32 | 2 | Ben |
| 09:41 | 3 | Ben |
| 08:52 | 1 | John |
| 09:24 | 2 | John |
| 09:42 | 3 | John |

I essentially need to add another column called completion time which is the difference between the time of the first stage and third stage for each name. So my output should look like this:

| Time | Stage | Name | Comp_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09:00 | 1 | Ben | 00:41 |
| 09:32 | 2 | Ben | 00:41 |
| 09:41 | 3 | Ben | 00:41 |
| 08:52 | 1 | John | 00:50 |
| 09:24 | 2 | John | 00:50 |
| 09:42 | 3 | John | 00:50 |

I've tried using a CTE and aggregates but doesn't get me what I needed.
The logic in my head makes sense, I just don't know how to translate that into SQL. Essentially For each name I need the difference in time between stage 1 and stage 3, with the results listed in a new column.

I don't even know where to begin with this, never had to compare 2 values in the same column before. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do names always have 3 stages each or can there be others, or multiple blocks of stages per name?

Comment: Always same stages, but sometimes a name can have multiple of the same stage, so 3 stage 1's for a name, in which case the min value for stage 1 for that name is what should be used in the calculation

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a basic update:

```
update yourtable, (
  select s3.Name, timediff(s3.Time,s1.Time) as d
  from yourtable s1
    join yourtable s3 on s1.name=s3.name
  where s1.Stage=1 and s3.Stage=3
  ) as d
set Comp_Time = d.d
where yourtable.Name=d.Name;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yR9kfc52)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using SQL window functions to calculate the completion time for each name. Specifically, you can use the `MIN` and `MAX` functions along with the `OVER` clause to partition the data by name and order it by stage. Then, you can calculate the time difference between the first and third stages for each name. Here's the SQL query to achieve that

```
SELECT Time,Stage,Name,
  TIMEDIFF(MAX(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY Name), MIN(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY Name)) AS Comp_Time
FROM your_table;
```

This query will give you the desired output with the completion time calculated for each name. The `MAX(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY Name)` gives you the time of the third stage for each name, and `MIN(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY Name)` gives you the time of the first stage for each name. The `TIMEDIFF` function calculates the time difference between these two values.